# distributing social login applications appKeys

Tags: facebook, twitter-oauth

I'm developing a commenting application where users can comment with their Facebook or Twitter accounts. My question is if i can distribute this projects with a universal Facebook/Twitter appKeys, Or every developer would have to create their own app in the respective social sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook and twitter are most used social networking sites and both  facebook  and twitter stores apikey and secret in their database to authenticate their user so a universal api key and secret can't be created and hence every developer need to create their own api key and secret for the respective sites.